# Three layouts that do the same thing for one activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Fairly new to the coding game and would like to know if and how I can do the following in Android Studio.
I have an activity for a type of game and three layouts for it: `layout_main`, `layout_opt1`, `layout_opt2`. They all do the same thing, just have different designs so the user can choose the best for his/her need or preference.

The user can switch between them on button press, but my issue is that when I switch from one to any of the others it does not display the data that was in the last one, even if I use the same ids for the fields and would like to know how can I prevent that from happening.

Unfortunately, I have no code for this now because I deleted the project to start from scratch due to other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most cost effective way to do the thing that you want to do. This method saves memory and doesn't force android to re-draw the whole layout on the display thus saving a lots of process as well as memory.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConstraintLayout layout;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet1 = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintSet constraintSet2 = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintSet constraintSet3 = new ConstraintSet();
    private byte count = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        constraintSet1.clone(layout);
        constraintSet2.clone(this,R.layout.layout_opt1);
        constraintSet3.clone(this,R.layout.layout_opt2);
    }
    public void changeLayout(View view) {
        if (count == 1){
            constraintSet2.applyTo(layout);
            count = 2;
        }
        else if (count == 2){
            constraintSet3.applyTo(layout);
            count = 3;
        }else {
            constraintSet1.applyTo(layout);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Use your own logic for the view change. I have used a counter logic to keep the track of the layout change. You can use other logic like using Boolean variables or using multiple buttons and then handling their onClicks separately in each setting the layouts.

Just keep in mind that you have to use the same views with same ids in all the layouts.
If you do not want to show any view in some layout just change the visibility of that view in that layout either from java code or XML code.

**layout_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:onClick="changeLayout"
    android:text="Change Layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="BTN A"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="BTN B"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**layout_opt1.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:onClick="changeLayout"
    android:text="Change Layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text=" BTN A"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="BTN B"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**layout_opt2.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:onClick="changeLayout"
    android:text="Change Layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="BTN A"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="BTN B"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can see in the above layouts all the views are same.

Comment: One more question related to this. One of the layouts should not change on phone rotation. Based on what I found in other posts, screen orientation is prevented from the manifest. Is there any line which I can include in the xml of my layout or should I prevent orientation change programatically when the user changes to that specific layout?

Answer (score 1):

You said the layouts do the same thing, but has different designs. Can you please express how are the designs different? (Like different buttons or backgrounds or else, as you said it's a game)
It's hard to suggest something not understanding the concept clearly.

Depends how you are changing the layouts.
You can use fragments or try setting Visibility(View/Gone) of the widgets keeping data & functionalities in the same activity persistent. But can't say for sure without enough info.
Thanks.

Comment: Each layout has exactly the same elements, but they are grouped in a different way. For example I have something like a score board than can be either at the bottom of the screen, or at the middle as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use 3 different layouts for a Activity use type like 1,2,3.

1. layout_main.xml
2. layout_opt1.xml
3. layout_opt2.xml

and before setcontent view check type, and then onsetcontentview set your desired layout and call methods for that specific layout using type check.

### Second trick

you can use fragments for better management of code.

### Third Trick

Use `<include/>` to add  different view to single xml file.
and set visibility to that layout according to types.

### Fourth Trick

use `ConstraintSet`  for better optimization and memory management.